# How to retrieve data in a normalize database

Tags: database

i have three tables `tbl_patient` `tbl_info` and `tbl_employee`. `tbl_info` contains all the information of both employees and patient. My problem is i dont know how to retrieve the patient information in the `tbl_info` without getting the employee information.

Comment: You should research on SQL joins.  If you post the table definitions for all tables involved, maybe someone can help you further.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you

Answer (score 0):

Acourding to your question, i think the most suitable solution is to do a SQL join between `tbl_patient` and `tbl_info`.

Comment: this could have been a comment on the question